# Trying to make a Google authentication by sending infos from React to Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to set up authentication using React and Laravel RESTFUL API. The issue is that I get info by clicking on the Login button. I want to complete the authentication by sending the data to the Laravel API and redirects to another page if it's verified and authenticated.
Thanks for helping me!

```js
responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
}

toggleLoggedIn = () =>
    this.setState(state => {
        return { isLoggedIn: !state.isLoggedIn };
    });


onSuccess = googleUser => {
    this.toggleLoggedIn();

    let user = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    let id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    console.log('google user obj', user);
    console.log('google_id_token', id_token);

    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api/google/callback`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + res.responseText);
         });
    }
```

```html
<GoogleLogin 
    clientId="Client id"
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
    onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
    />
```

I actually get Infos "in console" when clicking on the button. But I want to send them to the server and complete the authentication. Then redirect to another page.

Comment: This may be a good starting point - https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-google-guard

Comment: @levi Thanks ! I'll look it up !